# Take control of text styled with css columns attribute

Tags: html, css, css-multicolumn-layout

**Ingredients:** a `div` containing some text which we don't know the length of. What we know about the text is just it contains some keywords, `'mango'` for example, and those keyword must placed at the start of a new column (like those keyword are *subtitles*).

**Question:** Is there a way to achieve this goal with HTML5 + CSS3 (**preferably** without using JS, jQuery or some *script-based-patches*)?

**Actual situation (DEMO):**

```css
div {
  columns: 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud MANGO ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

**EDIT:** To understand better the question, I add the note that we don't know anything about the text that will be shown. So it **may** contain the **keyword** (in this case `mango`) or not. The aim of the question is how to take control over the text that will be shown.

Comment: what's the purpose of this? wouldn't you end up with two columns which are different sizes but backwards (little column on the left instead of on the right)?

Comment: The pourpouse is to avoid the keyword (in this example *mango*) to be shown in the last row of the first column so to take control over the text that will be shown with this style. If the keyword is not present, then nothing happens. Imagine that the keyword will be the subtitle of a list, it wouldn't be so nice that the title is shown as the last word in the left column, wouldn't it?

Comment: oh, then is this for a list or a body of text like you've used in your demo?

Comment: @Anthony
It's for both! The text to be shown *MAY* contain a list with a subtitle, but it's not mandatory: a body of text like I've used in my demo it's acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way, where one replace the capitalized words so the will be wrapped in an element along with their following text.

*With this you can also deal with 2 words and get 3 columns etc.*

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var div = document.querySelector('div');
  div.innerHTML = '<span>' + div.innerHTML.replace(/(\b[A-Z]+\b)/g, '</span><span>$1') + '</span>'
});
```

```css
div {
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;
  columns: 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div span {
  display: block;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud MANGO ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
  reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

---

If you get issues with browser support, here is a Flexbox version

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var div = document.querySelector('div');
  div.innerHTML = '<span>' + div.innerHTML.replace(/(\b[A-Z]+\b)/g, '</span><span>$1') + '</span>'
});
```

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div span + span {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud MANGO ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

---

And here is a Table version

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var div = document.querySelector('div');
  div.innerHTML = '<span>' + div.innerHTML.replace(/(\b[A-Z]+\b)/g, '</span><span>$1') + '</span>'
});
```

```css
div {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
div span {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud MANGO ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

---

If you want to style and/or have the capitalized word on a line by itself, you simply wrap it an extra element `'</span><span><span>$1</span>'`

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var div = document.querySelector('div');
  div.innerHTML = '<span>' + div.innerHTML.replace(/(\b[A-Z]+\b)/g, '</span><span><span>$1</span>') + '</span>'
});
```

```css
div {
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;
  columns: 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div span {
  display: block;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}

div span span {
  /* display: inline-block;       uncomment this to avoid new line  */
  color: orange;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud MANGO ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
  reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```